# React call function with conditional const and return

Tags: reactjs

I'm really new to React and trying to learn the basics so I'm just doing a simple little project to show some prices from different categories, just as a learning project. However I'm stuck in getting data from another function with a condition.

Here is my current code

PriceList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import './PriceList.css';

function CategoryList(props) {
    const categories = props.categories.map((cat) =>
        <ListGroup variant="flush">
            {cat.title}
            {PriceList.content}
        </ListGroup>
    )

    return (
       <div className="PriceList col-md-4">
               {categories}
       </div>                                    
    );
}

function PriceList(props) {

  const content = <ListGroup.Item>{props.service} - {props.price}:-</ListGroup.Item>;


  return (
     {content}
  );
}

export const Categories = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Category 1'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Category 2'}
];

export const Prices = [
  {id: 1, catid: 1, service: 'Category 1 Price 1', price: 199},
  {id: 2, catid: 1, service: 'Category 1 Price 2', price: 99},
  {id: 3, catid: 1, service: 'Category 1 Price 3', price: 199},
  {id: 4, catid: 2, service: 'Category 2 Price 1', price: 99},
  {id: 5, catid: 2, service: 'Category 2 Price 2', price: 199},
];

export default CategoryList;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import header from './header.jpg';
import ButtonToolbar from 'react-bootstrap/ButtonToolbar';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import './App.css';

import CategoryList from "./components/PriceList";
import {Categories} from "./components/PriceList";

function App() {
        return (
            <div className="App">

                <div className="App-header">

                    <img src={header} alt="Header" width="100%" />

                    <div className="App-link">

                        <ButtonToolbar>
                        <Button variant="outline-secondary">Stockholm</Button>
                        <Button variant="outline-secondary">Horndal</Button>
                        </ButtonToolbar>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <CategoryList categories={Categories} />


            </div>
        );
}
```

Perhaps you understand what I'm trying to do but I'll explain anyway.
I got 2 categories, and 5 different prices divided into thoose categories, so I want to render the prices sorted into one list per category.

Any tips on how to do this? If I'm doing it completely wrong please tell me.

I want the result to look like this

Category 1

Category 1 Price 1
  Category 1 Price 2
  Category 1 Price 3

Category 2

Category 1 Price 1
  Category 1 Price 2

Updated PriceList.js to this

```
import React from 'react';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import './PriceList.css';

function CategoryList(props) {
    const categories = props.categories.map((cat) =>
        <ListGroup variant="flush">
            {cat.title}
            <PriceList prices={Prices} />
        </ListGroup>
    )

    return (
       <div className="PriceList col-md-4">
               {categories}
       </div>                                    
    );
}

function PriceList(props) {

  const content = props.prices.map((price) =>
    <ListGroup.Item>{price.service} - {price.price}:-</ListGroup.Item>
  )


  return (
    <>
     {content}
    </>
  );
}

export const Categories = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Category 1'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Category 2'}
];

export const Prices = [
  {id: 1, catid: 1, service: 'Category 1 Price 1', price: 199},
  {id: 2, catid: 1, service: 'Category 1 Price 2', price: 99},
  {id: 1, catid: 1, service: 'Category 1 Price 3', price: 199},
  {id: 2, catid: 2, service: 'Category 2 Price 1', price: 99},
  {id: 1, catid: 2, service: 'Category 2 Price 2', price: 199},
];

export default CategoryList;
```

Now it does print everything twice though. So it prints all prices both in category 1 and 2.

Thought that I could use something like

```
const content = props.prices.find(props.prices.catid === props.catid).map((price) =>
    <ListGroup.Item>{price.service} - {price.price}:-</ListGroup.Item>
)
```

But doesn't work.

Best Regards
Cisco

Comment: What is `ListGroup` and `ListGroup.Item` in your code? Could you include all relevant code, including where you are using these components?

Comment: @Tholle ListGroup and ListGroup.Item is bootstrap components. This is all relevant code. All I want to do is call the CategoryList function and get all the items in the constant lists sorted by category ID in the correct constant category. But I'll edit the original post.

Comment: @Tholle main post edited.

Comment: `{content}` not wrapped in a component won't work. Either just return `content` or wrap it in a `React.Fragment`.

Comment: @Sulthan not really sure what you mean, calling a constant from within a function with {} works fine for me. Not that that's the question here.

Comment: @Cisco The problem is that `{PriceList.content}` definitely does not what you want. It should be `<PriceList services="..." prices="..."/>`. And as I am saying, returning `( {content} )` from a component is nonsense. It does not return JSX but plain javascript object `{ content: content }` which I am pretty sure is not what you want.

Comment: @Sulthan yes I just put `PriceList.content` there to show somewhat where I want to put it. Yes okey, but if I want to place all items from PriceList with ex. CatID=1 , how would I do that? And also, how do you think I should return the contect object? As I said, very new to React.

Comment: @Sulthan I updated the main post again.

Comment: I would think it would be something like `<PriceList prices={Prices.catid={categories.id}} />` but that seems to be totally wrong..

Comment: Just tried this
` const content = props.prices.find(props.prices.catid === props.catid).map((price) =>
 <ListGroup.Item>{price.service} - {price.price}:-</ListGroup.Item>
  )`
But no success..

Comment: Anyone Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed so figure it out. Updated the PriceList function to this

```
  const content = props.prices.map((price) => {
      var item;
      if(price.catid === props.catid) {
        item = <ListGroup.Item>{price.service} - {price.price}:-</ListGroup.Item>;
      } else {item = null;}

      return item;
  });
```

And works!